# How to limit the speed of laptop fan using i8kmon configuration?

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature

I have a problem with my Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop overheating. As a solution, I used i8kutils with this config:

```
 # Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon) 0

# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto) 1

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 1

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0) {{1 1} 30 59 -1 40}
set config(1) {{2 2} 60 128 53 128}
```

I want to run my fan at medium speed all time, except for cases when temperature exceeds 60 degrees mark. But with this config, I get fan running at high speed even when the temperature is only at 55 degrees.

That's how it looks:

```
1411306941 acpi: Battery 0: Full, 100%
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
temp, left, right, ac state: 54 2 2 0
```

And so on. Any suggestions?